# ajax POST not working, can't figure why

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a simple AJAX function to send an id of an object to a php page

My function looks like this:

```
$(function(){      
    $("a.vote").click(function(){
        //get the id
        the_id = $(this).attr('id');
        alert(the_id);

        //ajax post
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: "?id="+the_id,
            url: "vote.php",
            success: function(msg)
            {
                $("span#message"+the_id).html(msg);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

My vote.php looks like this:

```
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
    // db setup removed

    // insert vote into db
    $q = "UPDATE votes SET vote = vote + 1 WHERE id = " . $_POST['id'];   
mysql_query($q);      
echo "You sent " . $_POST['id'];
}
```

When I execute my AJAX function, it appears that the vote.php is never run

I know that my AJAX function is being called correctly, because alert(the_id); is popping up with the correct ID.

I know my vote.php is functioning correctly because I can run an HTML method="post" with a textbox named "id", and it will update the database correctly.

Can anyone see what's wrong?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to send your variables in the URL, not as POST variables. Should be something like:

```
$(function(){      
    $("a.vote").click(function(){
        //get the id
        var the_id = $(this).attr('id');
        alert(the_id);

        //ajax post
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: {id:the_id},
            url: "vote.php",
            success: function(msg)
            {
                $("span#message"+the_id).html(msg);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Your data should be as included as an object, not as a string URL. Check out the examples on the [jquery API](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) page for more info on this!

Answer (score 2):

The principal thing I see in your code that doesn't look right is `data: "?id="+the_id,`.  The `?` is unnecessary, and illogical for a post request.  Do the following instead:

```
data: {
    id: the_id
}
```

This lets jQuery do the URL-encoding for you.

As an additional point, you do `$(this).attr(id)`.  This is very inefficient.  Do `this.id` instead, for exactly the same effect <s>hundreds of times quicker</s> [at least 20 times quicker](http://jsperf.com/native-properties-vs-jquery-attr).

Answer (score 1):

Your `data` value shouldn't need a question mark at the beginning.